# C sizeOf operator : Want to make myOwnSizeOf( ) function

Tags: c, sizeof

We are all familiar with working of `sizeof` operator in C language. I am trying to make a similar working function that will absorb any kind of datatype and return me its size.

Can somebody tell me how to make such a similar function in "C".

```
int myOwnSizeOf(/*what would be parameter type?*/)
{
    //and what about the definition?
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the original `sizeof`?

Comment: It's an *operator* for a reason. You can't.

Comment: @PeterK - as an academic exercise I could see the value ... until you researched it and figured out it wasn't possible.

Comment: There is no way to do this in C.  sizeof isn't a function, it's an operator built into the language and there is no way to write a function that does the same thing.

Comment: C has no overloading of functions so this can't work.

Comment: @JensGustedt i was looking for some OOP in C..:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a function is evaluated at runtime, it can never consume a datatype but only objects. That's why `sizeof` is a built in operator.

You might get it to work for this limited case in C++ with a template function. But in C your only possibilities to consume an object of any datatype are either void pointers or macros. But the former won't work, of course, as it looses any type information and the latter was already suggested by aschepler and as he noted, it won't buy you anything (and it isn't a function, anyway).

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that with a function.  That's why `sizeof` is an operator built into the language, not a library function.  It's magic.

You could do

```
#define myOwnSizeOf(x) (sizeof(x))
```

but I don't really see the point.

Comment: Thanks..but isn't there any way to consume any kind of data type at run time like in objective C ("id").

Comment: void pointer: `void*` (Which of course still doesn't help you)

Comment: @Pankaj: No, not in C.  As Brian points out, you can try to pass the address of a variable as a `void *` (meaning you cannot pass integer or float literals as arguments), but then you've thrown away exactly the type information you need.  C simply doesn't support any sort of reflection capability, at least not natively.

Answer (score 0):

A function can't do it, but a macro can, if you don't mind throwing in a little technical UB that can't/won't really matter:

```
#define mysizeof(T) (size_t)((char *)((T*)0+1)-(char *)0)
```

If you replaced 0 with the address of a static-storage-duration object larger than any other object you'd ever try to take the size of, the UB would go away.

**Edit:** Note that this is for types `T`; a version for variables is much easier:

```
#define mysizeof(v) (size_t)((char *)(&v+1)-(char *)&v)
```

Comment: Do you have a version without UB short of the modification I suggested?

Comment: something like `offsetof(struct { T a; char b}, b)` :)

Comment: Try `offsetof(struct { T a[2]; }, a[1])`.

Comment: I don't think that `offsetof` is supposed to work with that. gcc is ok with that but clang says "using extended field designator is an extension" when using `-pedantic`.

Comment: I think it's unclear whether the standard intends for this to be possible or not. *The type and member designator shall be such that given static type t; then the expression &(t.member-designator) evaluates to an address constant.* It's possible that member-designator must actually be a strict direct member of the struct, but I think there's also an argument to be made that `offsetof` should be valid whenever `md` is such that `&(t.md)` is an address constant.